# autossh just does ssh; where is the magic?

Tags: ssh, autossh

I did

```
autossh -L 5901:localhost:5901 general
```

and got just command shell of `general` machine. Tunneling was working. After I exited the shell, tunnel was closed.

What is the difference with just `ssh`? I was thinking it will keep tunnel for me.

Comment: Did you also compare how they work when you temporarily disconnect a network cable?

Comment: I downvoted this question because it could have been answered simply by reading the doc ... Lazyness isn't a good choice, especially for trivial question like this.

Answer (score 3):

Autossh restarts the SSH connections as necessary, as long as the user doesn’t stop the connection:

> If the ssh process exited normally (for example, someone typed
>        "exit" in an interactive session), autossh exits rather than 
>        restarting;

(from [the Autossh `README.txt`](https://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/README.txt)).

Autossh improves SSH’s behaviour when SSH fails, or the connection drops for whatever reason, but it won’t keep a connection up for you if you close the connection yourself.